# How to retrieve the location of a device

Tags: java, android, gps

I want to retrieve the longitude and latitude of a device and just edit a textview with the data I obtained..
Here is where I left because I dunno what to do:

```
public class Login_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_activity);
    final TextView locationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final Button locationRetrieveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Location locationConst = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    final double locationX = locationConst.getLatitude();
    final double locationY = locationConst.getLongitude();
    final View.OnTouchListener retrieveButtonClicked = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            locationText.setText("FirstX:"+locationX+"\nFirstY="+locationY+"\nSecondX=\nSecondY=\n"+locationConst.getProvider());
            return false;
        }
    };
    locationRetrieveButton.setOnTouchListener(retrieveButtonClicked);
}
```

When I click the  "locationRetrieveButton" the locationX and locationY variables just return 0.0 and 0.0, the GPS_PROVIDER is "gps".
I've included all needed permissions in the android manifest (Coarse location and fine location and internet permissions as well).
What am I missing ?

Comment: check the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Comment: good tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure you add the permissions;

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="com.projectname.project.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
> ```

- In OnCreate Method;

  ```
      locationRetrieveButton.setOnTouchListener(retrieveButtonClicked);
      Location location = null;
      LocationManager locationManager=null;
        final View.OnTouchListener retrieveButtonClicked = new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

          try {
              locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext()
                      .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

              isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                      .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

              isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                          .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                  if (isGPSEnabled || isNetworkEnabled) { // Internet Or Gps Control

                      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                      return;
                  } //Check Permission

                      if (isGPSEnabled) { //Check Gps Enabled
                          if (location == null) {
                              locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000 , 10,
                                      new LocationListener() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                                          }

                                          @Override
                                          public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                                          }

                                          @Override
                                          public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                                          }

                                          @Override
                                          public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
                                          }
                                      });

                              if (locationManager != null) {
                                  location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


                              }

                          }}



                      //Check Network Enabled
                      if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                  LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                  2000,
                                  10,  new LocationListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                                      }

                                      @Override
                                      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                                      }

                                      @Override
                                      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                                      }

                                      @Override
                                      public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
                                      }
                                  });

                          if (locationManager != null) {
                              location = locationManager
                                      .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                          }
                      }


              }
               else {
                  AlertDialog alertMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
                  alertMessage.setTitle("Message");
                  alertMessage.setMessage("Please Open Internet Or Gps");
                  alertMessage.show();
              }
              }

       catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: if (location == null) {
location here should equal to what ?

Comment: There is a control of empty or filled.

Comment: nah, I mean where did you set the variable location in the code
location is not specified anywhere in the code